# Is it acceptable to use the Indicatif in the "avant que" clause?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps, subjonctif

> Mais ils ont voulu me faire filer avant que je le **vois / voie**.

Or does "avant que" always have to be followed by the Subjonctif, even in casual speech?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Avant que* always needs the subjunctive.

The [subjunctive](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/subjunctive/) has nothing to do with formality. The best example of this is hearing a teenager announce to his friends *il faut que je m'en aille*.

Comment: +1 For stressing it has nothing to do with formality. You could add to your answer that the verb following *avant que* requires the subjunctive because the subjunctive is the mood that expresses uncertainty and obviously  we don't know beforehand if an action will take place before... it has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

Although the [*ne explétif*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expl%C3%A9tif#La_semi-n.C3.A9gation_.C2.AB_ne_.C2.BB) isn't obligatory according to some, I would use it in your sentence.

It's syntactic role is to emphasize semi-negation. Action not being held/never going to be held.

Full sentence would be :
[...] avant que je **ne** le voie.